# Jquery: Append a ui dialog to a div on an HTML page

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code that when a button is clicked, it pops up the following dialog:

```
$(termsHTML).dialog({

                modal: true,
                //append:'#mainarea', tried adding it in here,also didnt work
                resizable: false,
                width: 400,
                height: 600,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                open: function (event, ui) {

                    $(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();

                    //var test = $(this).parent(); tried to append this part to the main area
                    //(test).append('#mainarea');
                },

                title: "Terms & Conditions",
                buttons: [{
                    text: "Decline",
                    "class": 'btnDialog',
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                    }
                },
                        {
                            text: "Accept",
                            "class": 'btnDialog',
                            click: function () {
                                btnAccept_onClick();
                                $(this).dialog("close");

                            }
                        }]
            });
```

However i I'm now trying to append it to the following block:

```
<div id='mainarea'></div>
```

.I am unable to get the dialog to be loaded inside the mainarea div,The parts in the code that is commented out is what i tried to get it to append but its not working.

also tried sayin

```
$('#mainarea').append(termsHTML.dialog());
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't think your question is clear about what you expect to achieve by appending the dialog to that div. It could be useful to provide us with a wireframe of the UI design you hope to achieve.

The idea of dialogs appearing above everything is because it is good UI design. If you have a dialog (especially one that prevents other actions) that appears underneath items or within specific areas it can be obstructive to the user.

Comment: I want it to be appended to that mainarea div and then i will be able to take care of the items that would cause any obstruction, the original request was to have it pop up now its changed to be placed differently,so now i cant figure out how to do so

Answer (score 0):

```
dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
dynDiv.id = "message1";
document.getElementById("divparent1").appendChild(dynDiv);
var test = dialog_box(dynDiv, AlertTest.message1.buttons);
```

Please Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/qNGEw/46/